# Greedy approach for maximum units in a truck

Tags: java

Here is a question which tells that boxTypes[0] contains number of boxes and boxTypes[1] tells how many units are there in each boxtype. trucksize tells how many boxes a truck can hold. We have to find maximum number of units a truck can hold.
My approach is to use greedy solution by sorting w.r.t number of units in each box and then subtract the trucksize with number of boxes.
The code snippet is like this

```
public int maximumUnits(int[][] boxTypes, int truckSize) {
       int c = 0;
       TreeMap<Integer, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();
       for(int[] i : boxTypes){
           m.put(i[1], i[0]);
       }
       for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> i : m.entrySet()){
           if(truckSize - i.getValue() > 0){
               c += i.getValue() * i.getKey();
               truckSize -= i.getValue();
           } else if(truckSize - i.getValue() == 0){
               c += i.getValue() * i.getKey();
               truckSize -= i.getValue();
               break;
           } else if(truckSize - i.getValue() < 0){
               c += (i.getValue() - truckSize) * i.getKey();
               break;
           }
       }
       return c;
   }
```

The input and output as as follows.
Input: boxTypes = [[1,3],[2,2],[3,1]], truckSize = 4
Output: 8
Explanation: There are:

- 1 box of the first type that contains 3 units.
- 2 boxes of the second type that contain 2 units each.
- 3 boxes of the third type that contain 1 unit each.
  You can take all the boxes of the first and second types, and one box of the third type.
  The total number of units will be = (1 * 3) + (2 * 2) + (1 * 1) = 8.

I don't understand why the code doesn't work, please help if I have missed some logic.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class x
{
  public static int maximumUnits(int[][] boxTypes, int truckSize)
  {
    //lets create some variablesbto store informationbas webloop
    int units = 0,openedBoxes = 0; boolean goToNextBox = true;
    for (int[] box : boxTypes)
    {
      if (goToNextBox) // we use thos to keep track of continuation of opening boxes
      {
        int noOfBoxTypes = box[0]; //loop number of box type times...
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfBoxTypes; i++)
        {
          units += box[1]; //add units according to the units in each box
          openedBoxes++; // increment opened box
          if (openedBoxes == truckSize) //test if box limit reached before opening next...
          {
            System.out.println("opened boxes = " + openedBoxes + " units = " + units
                               + "\n Now exiting loop...");
            goToNextBox = false; // now no more opening boxes
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      else break; // no need to continue loop since box limit will be reached if else executes
    }
    return units;
  }
  public static void main(String... a)
  {
    // This is the array in question... [[1,3],[2,2],[3,1]],
    System.out.println(maximumUnits(new int[][]{ new int[]{1,3},new int[]{2,2},new int[]{3,1} }, 4));
    /*
         Output ;
         opened boxes = 4 units = 8
         Now exiting loop...
         8
     */
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but its not the answer. See, it's given how many boxes a truck can hold. 2d array is given which tells that each box how many units it can contain. The greedy criteria is to maximize the number of units a truck can hold.

Comment: I picture this hierarchy...
`boxTypes[ box0[ unit0,unit1,unit2... ], box1[unit0,unit1,unit2,unit3..]...boxn[....unitn]]
` is this what is required

Comment: Hey Jore, I have added inputs and outputs to the question. Please check it.

Comment: @Shivaprasad Check the updated code...test it with more input...it yielded correct results with the array you provided...so i presume its correct...follow comments in code for explanation

Comment: Actually it works properly... i have tested `[ [1, 3], [3, 4], [2, 5] ]` and output is `20` ...good luck